# Login to facebook with credentials saved in database

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi i am trying to build a dashboard, this dashboard would be having facebook creds saved and would not require the user to login in, but this action should be performed in the background. currently when the user logs in to my dashboard he has to login to facebook by providing the username and password. I don't want the user to be entering the username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't and **should** not work (I also think this is agains the FB policies). When the user does have a FB session open (thus is on facebook.com logged in) the `FB.login()` method is aware of that since there is a cookie that it can access. Your page will likely ask for permissions and than log the user in. If the facebook.com session ends, your login times out or the user deletes the cookies, you have to log him in again.

There is no way to autmatically log the user in if there is no active session cookie.

Beside, logging the user in without telling him is bad no matter how you would solve it. The user needs to decide if the wants to login or not.

Comment: what if it is in concent with the user. but simply dont want to bother him with logging in all the time maybe only once